# Generic Types vs Abstract class/Interfaces

Tags: generics, interface, abstract-class

Suppose we are creating a generic control in .NET. E.g. a tree.
I don't understand why people use this generic type definition

```
Control<T>
```

when in Object Oriented Programming I can use an abstract class or an interface:

```
Control<IItem> or Control<BaseClass>
```

So the only thing to do is that, their types must derive from that base class or implement the
interface. 
Does it mean, that generic types are more convenient, because you I don't have to implement or inherit anything?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you a little bit confused. Generic types and abstract classes/interfaces serve different goals for different approaches in application design. Abstract classes/interfaces are for generalization of common functionality of a group of entities. Later on this API could be implemented differently, but since polymorphism is involved it will not impact anyone.

On other hand, sometimes you have a very similar implementation of something and the only difference is the type of the objects you are working with. Here you will need a generic. You could use polymorphism, but there is no need. For that purpose it's much clearer just to define an interface, make an implementation, and let the end user decide which kind of object to use.

The best example is List, where the main purpose of list is to store elements. The List implementor should not care which type of objects you are going to use, so later you will be able just define List and make use of integer list.

Comment: OK now I understand the difference, Thank you very much.

Comment: I came from the future to say thanks por your explanation :D

Answer (score 3):

Because in your case of a tree control, defining a generic Tree control would mean that Tree items can be of any type (you can also add certain constrains).

When instantiating a control, you would of course have to declare your item type (like in your second code examples with `IItem` and `BaseClass`).

If your Tree control wouldn't be a generic type, you would have to create several controls for each item type.

**Why not just use interface/abstractBase type?**
If you would just use an interface/abstract as your Item concrete class, you would be constrained by it's definition. You'd only see it's properties and methods. With generic Tree control and whatever item type, you're still able to access all item's properties and methods regardless of its interface implementation or parent class inheritance...

Comment: But I have 1 more question, what if I want to constraint the type T to have Parent and Children property and I don't use an interface. Is it possible?

Comment: @stefan - constraints have to be expressed via interfaces, apart from a few simple things: it is a value type (`where T : struct`), or a reference type (`where T : class`), or that it has a default constructor (`where T : new()`)

Comment: @stefan: of course you can do that as well without an interface as long as you define a class with those two properties and your item classes inherit from it. But it's generally much easier to use interface, because a class can implement multiple interfaces but inherit only one.

Comment: ...inherit only one class. Sorry.